# EEPROM Page Size Clarification

Tags: eeprom

Does Page size actually mean how many bytes i can read/write per read/write cycle?

for example a page size of 16 bytes means i can read/write in a single read/write?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34239/eeprom-page-size).

Comment: I saw it but it talks about writing only, so i was wondering if it also applies to reading?